# convert stable-baselines tensorflow model to tensorflowjs

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

**I am trying to convert the underlying tensorflow model from [stable-baselines](https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines) to [tensorflowjs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs) to be able to use the model on the browser. But I could not make the conversion work**

I followed [this github issue](https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines/issues/329) to create the necessary tensorflow files using the code:

```py
def generate_checkpoint_from_model(model, checkpoint_name):  
        tf.saved_model.simple_save(model.sess, checkpoint_name, inputs={"obs": model.act_model.obs_ph}, outputs={"action": model.action_ph})
```

Then I try to transform the model using [tensorflowjs_converter](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/conversion/import_saved_model)

```sh
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model test/ web_test
```

However, it gives me the following error:

```
Unable to lift tensor <tf.Tensor 'loss/action_ph:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32> because it depends transitively on placeholder <tf.Operation 'loss/action_ph' type=Placeholder> via at least one path, e.g.: loss/action_ph (Placeholder)
```

I created the following [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17g9sPh9I1NDFeHlp3T1VG_tKV6HUFL61) with the error so you can try it.

**Does anyone knows how to make this conversion work?**

Thank you for the help

Comment: Which version are you using for TensorFlow.js and TensorFlow? They both should be compatible with each other.

Comment: Someone just gave a -1 on the question and on the right answer below. Please do not do that for no reason since it does not help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the question as an [issue in stable-baselines](https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines/issues/474) and they answered. I will copy here as a reference to others:

> You are trying to save the action placeholder used in PPO training
>   (part of PPO agent), but for inference you only need the trained
>   policy and its placeholders (`model.act_model`). The code on colab runs
>   without errors by changing call to `simple_save` to this:
>
> `tf.saved_model.simple_save(model.sess, checkpoint_name,
>   inputs={"obs": model.act_model.obs_ph}, outputs={"action": model.act_model._policy_proba})`
>
> The value of _policy_proba [depends on the environment/algorithm.](https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines/blob/master/stable_baselines/common/policies.py#L233)